# How to avoid this error when I try to implement sign in with facebook button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, manifest, content-security-policy

I added Facebook signIn button and on `https://localhost:3000/` everything works just fine but when I deploy my app it throws the following error in the console:

> Refused to load the script 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://apis.google.com/ ".

I tried to add this line into my manifest.json: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://connect.facebook.net 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`
But it doesn't help. Could someone explain me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "**script-src-elem** 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

This violation message says that you use `script-src-elem` directive in the CSP. But you add the `https://connect.facebook.net` source into `script-src` directive.
Chrome browser follows the `script-src-elem` if it presents, and `script-src` is used as fallback only if `script-src-elem` is omitted.

You have to add `https://connect.facebook.net` into both `script-src-elem` and `script-src`.

Comment: this problem was actually on the back end side. This directive doesn't work because of the back end settings and seems like I can not override them on the client. Thank you for the answer.

Backend responses were with the following header: `content-security-policy: script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://apis.google.com/ style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/ `

Comment: Yeah, you can't on client override CSP published from back-end (both via meta and via header). On the client you can only add a second CSP via meta tag, but that makes summary CSP more restrictive.